# Cannot use document javascript object when running from Java

Tags: java, javascript

I have the following javascript code that runs from java:

```
var doc = document.implementation.createDocument('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'html',  null);
doc.documentElement.innerHTML = xmlResponse;
```

And I get the following error:

```
Caused by: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "document" is not defined. (<Unknown source>#13)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3773)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3751)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.notFoundError(ScriptRuntime.java:3836)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.name(ScriptRuntime.java:1762)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1790)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:854)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:164)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:429)
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine$1.superDoTopCall(RhinoScriptEngine.java:116)
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine$1.doTopCall(RhinoScriptEngine.java:109)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3163)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:175)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Context.evaluateReader(Context.java:1159)
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:210)
    ... 16 more
```

Do you have any clue of how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp):

> The window object represents an open window in a browser.

Since you are not executing your script in a browser, the window object is not defined.

You can read the URL using the URL/URLConnecion classes and feed it to the ScriptEngine. [There is a tutorial here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html).